# Push branches to Git

Tags: git, branch, github, git-push, git-pull

I have a local repository I'm working on and its remote is hosted on GitHub. I recently created a branch and started working on it, making several commits and now wish to push the branch to GitHub and be able to pull it to another cloned repository. How do I do this?

Comment: More info on workflow at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204499/631619

Comment: not the most insightful title for a question, ugh

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
git push origin <local-branch-name>:<remote-branch-name>
```

Substitute for `<local-branch-name>` and `<remote-branch-name>`. They may be same or different, as you wish.

Comment: Does that mean I can then do "git pull origin <REMOTE-branch-name>:<LOCAL-branch-name>"?

Comment: @PHLAK: Yes, you can use the same refspec for `git pull` as well.

Comment: @AlanHaggaiAlavi But that's not the same refspec.

Answer (score 18):

As you have set up the remotes already, the command is just

```
git push origin branch-name
```

on the first push.

Afterward, using `git push origin` would push all branches with the matching name on remote.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that your remote URL is using SSH syntax and not just Git protocol syntax. If you run,

```
git remote show origin
```

the URL printed should look something like,

```
git@github.com:yourname/projectname.git
```

You need the URL too to look like that if you want to be able to push. If you are just a public user (without write access) the URL will look like,

```
git://github.com/yourname/projectname.git
```

If yours looks like the latter then you can manually edit it in your projects `.git/config` file.

Comment: I can already push and pull to and from my GitHub repo, I'm just trying to figure out how to push and pull a branch.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to pull any branch code from remotely to locally

```
$git pull origin branch_name
```

while if you need to push code to your branch

**you need to check is your code successfully save
you can check by**

```
$git status
```

than

```
$git add -A
```

**after this make commit to your branch**

```
$git commit -m "this is initial change"
```

than(Last)
**push your code to your branch by:**

```
$git push origin branch_name
```

Comment: "git pull origin branch_name" - this does seem to pull into a new local branch if there were not any