# Pull a certain branch from the remote server

Tags: git, merge, branch, pull

Say that someone created a branch `xyz`. How do I pull the branch `xyz` from the remote server (e.g. [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)) and merge it into an existing branch `xyz` in my local repo?

The answer to
*[Push branches to Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072261/push-and-pull-branches-in-git)* gives me the error "! [rejected]" and mentions "non fast forward".

Comment: what is the actual command you're running?

Comment: It is fetch that can fail with 'non fast forward' message.  Did you modify remote-tracking branch (origin/xyz), or was the branch rewound / rewritten in remote repository?  Youmight need to use "`git fetch origin --force`", but please read documentation before doing it.

Comment: The remote could be, for example, a github URL, with a selected branch.. (see comment to Cabri's answer)

Answer (score 1041, accepted):

> But I get an error "! [rejected]" and something about "non fast forward"

That's because Git can't merge the changes from the branches into your current master. Let's say you've checked out branch `master`, and you want to merge in the remote branch `other-branch`. When you do this:

```
$ git pull origin other-branch
```

Git is basically doing this:

```
$ git fetch origin other-branch && git merge other-branch
```

That is, a `pull` is just a `fetch` followed by a `merge`. However, when `pull`-ing, Git will *only* merge `other-branch` *if* it can perform a *fast-forward* merge. A *fast-forward* merge is a merge in which the head of the branch you are trying to merge into is a *direct descendent* of the head of the branch you want to merge. For example, if you have this history tree, then merging `other-branch` would result in a fast-forward merge:

```
O-O-O-O-O-O
^         ^
master    other-branch
```

However, this would *not* be a fast-forward merge:

```
    v master
O-O-O
\
 \-O-O-O-O
         ^ other-branch
```

To solve your problem, first *fetch* the remote branch:

```
$ git fetch origin other-branch
```

Then merge it into your current branch (I'll assume that's `master`), and fix any merge conflicts:

```
$ git merge origin/other-branch
# Fix merge conflicts, if they occur
# Add merge conflict fixes
$ git commit    # And commit the merge!
```

Comment: No, the problem is with fetching, not with merge step.

Comment: Normally, remotes are set up such that fetches are forced, even if they don't result in a fast-forward commit, so it shouldn't occur on fetch unless the OP changed something with the usual configuration. The fast-forward issue can occur during fetch *or* merge. What makes you say that the problem is definitely in fetching, and not in merging?

Comment: I follow these steps (fetch, merge). Git tells me there's nothing to do. When I try to commit, it falls over moaning about fast-forwards.

Comment: @mipadi I had same issue as Jean and, while I can't say the remote is setup in the non default way you've mentioned I can say using `git fetch -f` have fixed my issue! Thanks!

Comment: This merges remote branch `xzy` into local branch `master`, which is not what was implied by the original question; "How can I pull branch xyz from GitHub and merge it into branch xyz on my localhost?"

Comment: just FYI and my future reference as well, "git pull --rebase origin other-remote-branch" also works if you want to rebase.

Comment: What is you don't want to merge?

Answer (score 384):

Simply track your remote branches explicitly and a simple `git pull` will do just what you want:

```
git branch -f remote_branch_name origin/remote_branch_name
git checkout remote_branch_name
```

The latter is a local operation.

Or even more fitting in with the [GitHub documentation on forking](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo):

```
git branch -f new_local_branch_name upstream/remote_branch_name
```

Comment: If you get 'Not a valid object name: 'origin/remote_branch_name', do 'git fetch origin' first.

Comment: fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.

Answer (score 215):

A safe approach is to create a local branch (i.e. xyz) first and then pull the remote branch into your locals.

```
# create a local branch
git checkout -b xyz

# make sure you are on the newly created branch
git branch

# finally pull the remote branch to your local branch
git pull origin xyz
```

Here is the syntax that could pull a remote branch to a local branch.

```
git pull {repo} {remotebranchname}:{localbranchname}

git pull origin xyz:xyz
```

Comment: Perfect! I just didn't know that syntax: git pull {repo} {remotebranchname}:{localbranchname}. Question, if that pull doesn't work (maybe someone's updated the branch and there would be merge conflicts) what are my options?

Comment: Phrogz - looks like this behavior changed in recent versions of Git. I used this before and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: The answer is seriously misleading!!! I applied the answer without noticing @Phrogz 's comment and now suffering from the problem s/he mentioned. Either which branch it tries to merge should be expressed explicitly or the answer should be deleted !!!!

Comment: @Phrogz,@Letitbe which command did you try? I can change the answer accordingly. Never had the issue of pulling it into master.

Comment: The `{repo}` can also be a URL, so for quick looks at some other repo it can be nicer than having to create a remote first (stick the fetch/pull command in the new branch description;-)

Comment: @Phrogz the answer was adjusted, it now has 'git branch' to make sure the person is on the right branch. Like that when doing 'git pull' it will pull to that branch and not master, right?

Answer (score 122):

The best way is:

```
git checkout -b <new_branch> <remote repo name>/<new_branch>
```

Comment: After creating a new "dev" branch on github, and trying the above, I got the following error message: "fatal: origin/dev is not a commit and a branch 'dev' cannot be created from it" Solution was to "git fetch" per Bradley Flood's solution below, and then re-running mohit's answer.

Answer (score 66):

`git fetch` will grab the latest list of branches.

Now you can `git checkout MyNewBranch`

Done :)

---

*For more info see docs: [git fetch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)*

Comment: it worked fine git fetch, then git checkout remoteBranch

Answer (score 47):

I am not sure I fully understand the problem, but pulling an existing branch is done like this (at least it works for me :)

```
git pull origin BRANCH
```

This is assuming that your local branch is created off of the origin/BRANCH.

Comment: This will pull the branch into your current local branch, so when you are on `dev` and to `git pull origin feature` it will pull the feature branch into `dev`. The person who asked the question wants to make a new branch `feature` and pull into this branch

Comment: but first you need to do `git checkout -b xyz` then you do `git pull origin xyz`

Answer (score 26):

Simply put, If you want to pull from GitHub the branch `the-branch-I-want`:

```
git fetch origin
git branch -f the-branch-I-want origin/the-branch-I-want
git checkout the-branch-I-want
```

Comment: WOW It worked!! Normally I would do

`git checkout -b branch-i-want
git pull origin branch-i-want` Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

This helped me to get remote branch before merging it into other:

```
git fetch repo xyz:xyz
git checkout xyz
```

Answer (score 17):

for pulling the branch from GitHub you can use

```
git checkout --track origin/the-branch-name
```

Make sure that the branch name is exactly the same.

Answer (score 10):

These work for me.

1. To pull a specific remote branch to the current local branch you are in.
   (Where `<remote_repo>` is the remote repository and `<remote_branch>` is the specific remote branch you want to pull)

```
git pull <remote_repo> <remote_branch>
```

e.g.

```
git pull origin remote_master
```

2. To pull a specific remote branch to a specific local branch.
   (Where `<local_branch>` is the specific local branch you want to pull into)

```
git pull <remote_repo> <remote_branch>:<local_branch>
```

e.g.

```
git pull origin remote_master:local_master
```

Answer (score 9):

I did

```
git branch -f new_local_branch_name origin/remote_branch_name
```

Instead of

```
git branch -f new_local_branch_name upstream/remote_branch_name
```

As suggested by @innaM. 
When I used the upstream version, it said 'fatal: Not a valid object name: 'upstream/remote_branch_name''. I did not do `git fetch origin` as a comment suggested, but instead simply replaced `upstream` with `origin`. I guess they are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

you may also do

```
git pull -r origin master
```

fix merge conflicts  if any

```
git rebase --continue
```

-r is for rebase.
This will make you branch structure from

```
        v  master       
o-o-o-o-o
     \o-o-o
          ^ other branch
```

to

```
        v  master       
o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o
              ^ other branch
```

This will lead to a cleaner history. 
Note: In case you have already pushed your other-branch to origin( or any other remote), you may have to force push your branch after rebase.

```
git push -f origin other-branch
```

Answer (score 6):

```
git pull <gitreponame> <branchname>
```

Usually if you have only repo assigned to your code then the gitreponame would be origin.

If you are working on two repo's like one is local and another one for remote like you can check repo's list from **git remote -v**. this shows how many repo's are assigned to your current code.

BranchName should exists into corresponding gitreponame.

you can use following two commands to add or remove repo's

```
git remote add <gitreponame> <repourl>
git remote remove <gitreponame>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try with

```
git branch -a
```

or `git fetch` to get latest list of branches.

`git checkout theBranch` //go in to the branch

`git checkout -b "yourNewBranch"` // to work in your own branch in base "theBranch"

Answer (score 4):

### A simple solution to get new branch from remote to local

1. fetching the remote branch

   `git fetch xyz`
2. switch to that branch locally

   `git switch xyz`
3. finally, check if xyz appears on your local branches by running

   `git branch`

Answer (score 2):

### The Local User Needs to Update Both the Master Branch and the XYZ Branches Separately

**None of these posts answers the original question!**

> How do I pull the branch xyz from the remote server (e.g. GitHub) and
> merge it into an existing branch xyz in my local repo?
> The answer to Push branches to Git gives me the error "! [rejected]"
> and mentions "non fast forward".

If you want to merge a remote `xyz` branch into a local `xyz` branch, where both branches exist off a master branch in a remote and local repository, just select or "checkout" the local `xyz` branch first, then do a "pull" on the same remote branch. Simple!

```
git checkout xyz
git pull origin xyz
```

### But, the user got an error! That update did not work. Why?

**If this is failing**, it has nothing to do with the two `xyz` branches on remote and local repositories not being able to merge. It sounds like the **master branch** on the remote repository has been changed with new commits the local repository does not have. The fast-forward message likely means that the `xyz` branch on the remote repo cannot update the local repo's `xyz` branch until the **local repo gets all the changes added to its master branch from the remote repo first**.

These could be new commits or changes the other developer added to the remote master branch, who then ran a rebase on their `xyz` branch to move it to the end of those new commit HEADS in the remote master. The local repo user has no way to merge that change as its master branch is missing those new added commits at the end, so cannot update the `xyz` rebase change until its local master branch on its repo is updated with a merge via a `pull`, first.

So go ahead and update the local master with the remote master's updates first using a `pull`, then try your `xyz` branch `pull` again...

```
git checkout master
git pull origin

git checkout xyz
git pull origin xyz
```

Remember, a `pull` is just a `fetch` then `merge` from a remote repo to your local repo on whatever branch you are currently focused on.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

- 1 step : checkout to local branch "xyz" `git checkout`
- 2 step : fetch the changes but not update like directly.So use "`git fetch`" for xyz to update local repositary.
- 3 step : merge and fix the conflict if there is any. "`git merge`".