# Doing Hot Fixes on Heroku with Git Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, git-branch, git-tag

Hoping somebody can point me in the right direction here. I want to better understand how my application is deploying a tag to Heroku and how I can take advantage of that to use a combination of tags/branches to make hot fixes to production. I have a rails 3.1 app running on Heroku.

This is some output from my custom deploy rake task for demo

```
git push origin tag deploy.120716134715
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:myusername/myrepository.git
 * [new tag]         deploy.120716134715 -> deploy.120716134715

deploy tag deploy.120716134715 was created
git push demo deploy.120716134715:master --force
Everything up-to-date

git tag demo.120716134726 deploy.120716134715

git push origin tag demo.120716134726
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:myusername/myrepository.git
 * [new tag]         demo.120716134726 -> demo.120716134726
```

So I'm creating a deploy tag and pushing it to my heroku demo app then creating a demo tag from the deploy tag.

My production rake task output is similar:

```
Push deploy.120716132600 to Production?  Type 'y' to deploy
y
deploying
git push production deploy.120716132600:master --force
Counting objects: 19, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 1.42 KiB, done.
Total 15 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       All dependencies are satisfied
-----> Installing Exceptional plugin from git://github.com/exceptional/exceptional.git... done.
-----> Installing quick_sendgrid plugin from git://github.com/pedro/quick_sendgrid.git... done.
-----> Configuring New Relic plugin... done.
       Installing the New Relic plugin... done.
-----> Compiled slug size is 29.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v291
-----> Deploy hooks scheduled, check output in your logs
       http://my-app-production.heroku.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:my-app-production.git
   9d0f2ca..9827475  deploy.120716132600 -> master

git push origin refs/tags/deploy.120716132600:refs/tags/production.120716133802
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:myusername/myrepository.git
 * [new tag]         deploy.120716132600 -> production.120716133802
```

So the deploy tag is pushed to my Heroku production app and then a production tag is created and pushed to origin.

So my question is what is now the best approach to make hot fixes to production? Let's say I have changes in my master branch I've already commited locally and then pushed. What would be the best approach to taking what's on production pulling it down locally, modifiying it, committing it and pushing back to production without pushing the new changes that I've made to production?

Is this even possible?

Thanks for your help in advance everyone, and let me know what other information I need to provide. Like I said rails 3.1 app, a demo and a production app on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best approach to taking what's on production pulling it down locally, modifying it, committing it and pushing back to production without pushing the new changes that I've made to production?

Pull what's on production into a new branch, modify it, commit, and push that branch back up. See here for some relevant information: [Git pull a certain branch from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709177/git-pull-certain-branch-from-github)