# updating github pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Can I modify someone's pull request to my repository and add these modifications to that pull request?

Say A forked my repo, added a feature branch, and made a pull request on my repo. I want to make some changes to the pull request, and not necessarily merge it yet, but update the pull request. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-user Github Pull Requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592653/multi-user-github-pull-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer short: **No**. Not unless you have permission to edit that person's fork. You can, however, pull in the person's commits and work on top of them as shown below. Note that this will not modify the PR, but only enable you to keep the person's commits.

You could create a new branch. Then point a remote to the branch on which A submitted the PR, pull in changes from A's branch and then work on those changes.

Steps:
Assume A's fork lies at `https://github.com/repo/A.git` and A's branch name is `<A's_branch_name>`.

1. Create a new branch on Github (say `aBranch`).
2. Run a `git pull` to pull in the branch.
3. Change to the new branch using
   `git checkout aBranch`.
4. Create a remote pointing to A's branch using
   `git remote add aBranchRemote https://github.com/repo/A.git`.
5. Pull in A's changes with a
   `git merge aBranchRemote <A's_branch_name>`

PS: I've not tested these steps, but it should work fine. I faced a very similar situation yesterday, and this worked.

Comment: In which of these steps is the changes I make reflected in the pull request? Because I just tried creating a branch with the same name as `<A's_branch_name>`, pull all changes, make my new changes, and push this branch to my repo. Yet, the pull request is not changed, i.e. different from the branch on my repo.

Comment: sorry. updated the answer. You can't modify someone's PR unless you have write access to tehir branch, which Im assuming you dont. You can, however, work on top of their commits, as illustrated.

Comment: In case you do have access, however, its simply  matter of pulling their fork of the repo, and pushing directly to it, much like how you would do if the branch were your own. The PR will get automatically updated.