# Github push changes to someone else's branch

Tags: git, github

Following [these directions](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/) exactly, I reviewed a Github pull request #42 from developer Foo, then made some changes and pushed them. This created a new PR (#43) with everything from #42 plus my local changes; note I have not yet opened the PR on Github, it's just pushed. If I want Foo to still make changes on her branch, which originally pushed #42, what is my course of action?

More generally, how can I pull in a PR and push changes such that Foo and I can both work on the same PR?

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592653/multi-user-github-pull-requests) is related, but doesn't give a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that there is a remote repository repo1 of user1. The normal workflow for creating a pull request is: you fork user1's repo1 and start working in a branch (usually master).

**As a Git point of view, Pull Request doesn't even exist**... PR is just a facilitation provided by some Git hosts.

To Git there are two branches, one in the repo1 of user1 and other in your fork. Even when you create a PR, your branch continue to exist like any other branch. So, if you want to someone else collaborate with you in your branch (and consequently in the PR) you should give them write access to your repo and they will be able to push commits to it.