# Make change directly to GitHub branch

Tags: git, github, repository

Let's say I have my main branch in GitHub. Me and my friend want to make a second branch called testing where we can mess around with other code before merging it to the main branch. How can I add code to this testing branch. For example, lets say there is an HTML page in the testing branch and the main branch. How can I make changes to the one in the testing branch without touching the one in the main?

I saw slightly similar questions like [Github push changes to someone else's branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233840/github-push-changes-to-someone-elses-branch) but that did not help me.

I am using windows if that makes a difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+workflow+team

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do that is to pull the code to your local machine, make changes and push back to the remotes repository new branch.

`git pull` Get code from GitHub repository to your local machine

`git checkout -b testing` Switch to new branch. Make changes in your files here

`git commit -a -m "Some feature"` Commit changes to your testing branch

`git push --set-upstream origin testing` Push changes to GitHub to the new branch called "testing"