# git checkout seems to download from server

Tags: git

I'm using a remote git repository with multiple branches.

From the documentation I understand that I switch between branches by doing

```
git checkout master
```

or

```
git checkout branchname
```

I also understand that the repository is cloned onto my local machine (and that this is updated by doing git fetch)

But when I do

```
git checkout master

git checkout branchname

git checkout master
```

in quick succession the system clearly downloads stuff from the server
(at least, /sbin/ifconfig shows I'm downloading tens of megabytes)

What have I misunderstood here?

Comment: `ifconfig` is not a reliable means to measure your current bandwidth use for any particular application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> system clearly downloads stuff from the server

No, `git checkout` is a purely local operation, based on the full history of the repo cloned locally.
You could shut down any network connection that it would still work.

Even when you do a [checkout of a remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710427/6309) (also [described here](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/09/checkout-remote-tracked-branch.html)), it is still local (since said "remote" branch is actually fetched and stored in the local namespace called "remotes")

```
git checkout --track -b haml origin/haml
```

Comment: Yes, I now realise that the results of ifconfig, and the time it took, were the NFS connection to our local fileserver.  It seems that git works very badly with NFS