# No "pull" in Git Gui?

Tags: git-pull, git-gui

How can I make a pull using Git GUI tool? It seems there is no pull command anywhere.

Is there an equivalent menu option using Git GUI?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question have a meaningful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709177/git-pull-a-certain-branch-from-github

Comment: Why would one use Git GUI in the first place?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Well, I found this useful forum post:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200211180001/http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/No-quot-pull-quot-in-git-gui-td1121058.html

A fetch and merge should be done.

It seems you need to go to "Remote" menu, then "Fetch from" option , in my case origin, and then go to "Merge Menu" and then "Local Merge...".

Comment: I cannot sufficiently emphasize how dumb it is that in the CLI you need only type "git pull" to get a combined fetch and merge, but in the GUI, which should be easier, you must manually fetch and then merge.
It not only is easier from the command line, but someone who is even slightly familiar with the CLI will be searching for "pull", and it's not there. Makes no sense

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 96):

There is also a way to add the pull command to git gui.

When you open GIT GUI you can open the tab `Tools` and choose `Add` option.

You can enter a name, and as command enter `git pull`

This will add an option under the `Tools` tab. Just click this and a git pull will be done.

Considering [this answer](/a/22666879): it's not because a pull can be done that it should be done

Comment: in the dialog that appears after clicking Tools > Add make sure to add `git pull origin master` as the syntax is `git pull <remote> <branch>` assuming origin is the remote location from where you want to pull the changes, and also `origin` is set as the name in git gui from Remote > Add > in remote details name was written as origin, else make necessary changes as require for `<remote> name`

Comment: @John True, but not strictly necessary. When the remote and branch aren't specified Git assumes current branch and tracked remote. I actually prefer to just have it execute git pull and add globally (checkbox), since I have different remote names for different projects.

Answer (score 7):

This entry in .gitconfig works nicely for me:

```
[guitool "Pull"]
cmd = git pull $(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' $(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD) | tr / " ")
```

It automatically selects current remote branch.

Instruction above assumes that you've set your upstream prior. If you haven't done so then you can do it using command below. [NOTE: Run the command inside of your repository.]

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main master
```

Above command to set upstream is for a case where your *remote* is **origin** and *current branch* is **main**.