# Working on a project's Github page

Tags: git, github

I've just cloned a repo I have hosted on Github but this only checked out the `master` branch. There's also a `gh-pages` branch that Github creates automatically to host the project's site.

I want to also clone (checkout? pull?) this branch to work on it and I've found a lot of material on this that got me a bit confused.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72156/1391441) says that I should do:

```
git checkout -b gh-pages origin/gh-pages
```

and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710427/1391441) implies the command could be:

```
git branch -f gh-pages upstream/gh-pages
```

What is the difference between these two? Should I stick with the first one?

---

Add.  If I do `git branch -a` I get:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/gh-pages
remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first one creates a branch `gh-pages` if that branch doesn't exist.
- The second one forces an existing `gh-pages` branch to `upstream/gh-page`.

Personally, I prefer declaring [`gh-pages` branch as a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049125/6309).
That allows you to work on master, while seeing/updating the `gh-pages` content in a `gh-pages` subfolder (declared as a submodule).

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

So you don't even have to checkout another branch now (uf the upstream repo chose the new content organization)

Comment: And what does the first one do if the `gh-pages` branch already exists (my case)? Which one should I use if I want to work on my already existing `gh-pages` branch? I'll check out working with a submodule, never seen that before.

Comment: @Gabriel if the branch already exist, the command will fail. The second will not.

Comment: VonC tried the 2nd command (`git branch -f gh-pages upstream/gh-pages`) and I got: `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'upstream/gh-pages'.`

Comment: @Gabriel you need to adapt it to the name of your upstream repo: `git remote -v`: most likely 'origin' in your case. `git branch -f gh-pages origin/gh-pages`

Comment: @Gabriel the second answer you mention uses 'upstream' in the context of a GitHub fork: read my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309

Comment: Thanks for all the detailed answers @VonC!