# Git - pull origin master after creating local branch

Tags: git

I'm just learning git and can't understand what is happening when we execute `git pull origin master` after we created new local branch and there are new commits in remote master. Consider the following example:

1. There is one commit (aaaaaa) in origin master, for example initial commit.
2. I clone origin master
3. I create new local branch (new_feature), check out to it, and make commit (bbbbbb) to new_feature.
4. Someone makes new commit (cccccc) to origin master.

What is happening when I do `git pull origin master` after step 4? Please, explain.

Comment: Read the accepted answer in the duplicate link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709177/git-pull-a-certain-branch-from-github).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Could you remove your duplicate - that question considers situation that is much more complex than mine and I am a beginner, so I am asking the answer to this concrete example.

Comment: It covers the same situation as yours actually.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you can't help me, then let someone else do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709177/git-pull-a-certain-branch-from-github) largely explains what happens when you do a `git pull` from another remote branch.

```
# from new_feature
git pull origin master
```

The above is equivalent to this:

```
# from new_feature
git fetch origin master && git merge master
```

But, the kicker here is that in your case Git actually *won't* execute the above, because the merge is *not* a fast forward merge.  This is because your branches currently look like this:

```
master:      ... A -- C
                  \
new_feature:       B
```

That is, merging the `C` commit on top of `B` is more than just a simple replay, because there could be merge conflicts.

What you should instead be doing in this situation, and arguably what you always should do in this situation, is to just merge `master` into your feature branch:

```
# from new_feature
git fetch origin master
git merge origin/master
```

Note that there may be merge conflicts, which you would then have to fix, then make a commit to complete the merge.

After the commit, your branch should look like this:

```
master:      ... A -- C
                  \    \
new_feature:       B -- D
```

Commit `D` is a merge commit, and actually has both `B` and `C` as parents.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `git pull origin master` after step 4, git essentially tries to `fetch` and then merge the changes that are not present in your feature branch.

This process is well explained [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)