# Why I can't clone/pull a whole repository from github, only the README file?

Tags: git, github, clone, pull

Beginner GitHub user here, cannot figure out how to use it.

I have a repository, it has two branches, one is called main, and it has a README file, and there is another called master, with all my other files. Only a few files.

I pushed them from my desktop, and when I want to clone or pull the entire repository to my laptop, it only pulls the README file, nothing else; so basically the content of the branch called main.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git pull a certain branch from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709177/git-pull-a-certain-branch-from-github)

Comment: `git clone` will generate a local copy of the repo. Use `git checkout master` to switch to the branch with all the other files.

Answer (score 6):

When you clone a remote repository, by default your local working directory will be on the remote repository's default branch. For a long time this was the `master` branch, but GitHub has recently started using the name `main` instead of `master`.

It sounds like your repository may have been created someplace else and then pushed to GitHub. Regardless of how you arrived at this situation, you have two branches named `main` and `master`, and it sounds like `main` is the default branch.

After cloning the repository, you will be on the `main` branch. You can switch to the `master` branch by running:

```
git switch master
```

Or:

```
git checkout master
```

The `git switch` syntax is newer. The two commands are largely equivalent (`git checkout` does more than `git switch`).

---

You can change the default branch of  your GitHub repository by going to your repository settings. Clicking on "Branches" along the left. This will take you to the branch settings, where the first section is the "Default branch" section.

Click on the icon with two arrows, then select `master` as your default branch.

In the future, `git clone` will result in a working directory that is on the `master` branch.

Answer (score 2):

If you only see the *README.md* file, then you stay in the `main` branch. Every repository have a default branch. In your case is this the `main` branch. And this default branch is checked out automatically after `git clone`.

`git branch -a` lists all existing branches and also in which branch you currently stay. If you execute `git checkout master` (command for changing branches) you would be able to see also the other few files, because you are then in the other branch.