# git get a copy of a branch

Tags: git, download, branch, clone

how do I get a copy of a branch from a remote git server? I have tried the following options

```
git clone url
git clone url branchName
```

it looks they get the master copy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone a single branch in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the the `--branch` or `-b` option on clone:

```
git clone -b <name> url
```

See `man git clone` for further details.

Comment: While this is true, see the answer from ERR0 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

when you clone you get ALL the branches and history.

good explanation here:
[git branch, fork, fetch, merge, rebase and clone, what are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329943/difference-between-a-branch-fork-and-clone-in-git)

use:

> git-branch

once you clone the repository to see the branches in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone url
git branch branchname
git checkout branchname
git pull origin branchname
```

this works for me afa i remember. there might be some better way though, i'm not a git pro.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a new repo and then fetch the branch alone:

```
git init .
git fetch <url> <branchname>:refs/remotes/origin/<branchname>
git checkout <branchname>
```

---

Caveat about the other answer on `git clone -b`

Git *always* clones the entire repository. What you have in your working directory is based on which branch you checkout. So if you want a particular branch, clone the repo and checkout the repo.

`git clone -b` is the shortcut for doing that.

Again, you are not getting a "copy" of your branch, but the whole repo with the required branch checked out.