# How to abandon changes?

Tags: git

I often work from OpenSSL's git repo. One of the things I test my changes against is a clean copy by issuing `make clean; make dclean`.

When I performs `git pull`, git always fails because of all the developer cruft that's removed with `dclean` (see below). When it fails, git tells me to *"commit your changes or stash your changes..."*. I'm not interested in committing, saving or stashing them. Rather, I'd like to abandon them.

`git abandon` is not a command. What is the command to abandon changes?

---

A related question is [How do you discard unstaged changes in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52704/608639). But the answer is to stash them (if you read the question, you will see none of the answers actually *answers* the question). But I'm not interested in stashing or saving them. I just want abandon them so I can `git pull` and go back to work.

---

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 2069, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (872/872), done.
remote: Total 2069 (delta 1022), reused 589 (delta 589), pack-reused 608
Receiving objects: 100% (2069/2069), 3.13 MiB | 1.59 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1272/1272), done.
From https://github.com/openssl/openssl
   c40dba9..e0f9bf1  master     -> origin/master
   8a09500..d8a2353  OpenSSL-fips-2_0-dev -> origin/OpenSSL-fips-2_0-dev
   155ca14..f16093d  OpenSSL_0_9_8-stable -> origin/OpenSSL_0_9_8-stable
   690d040..aaa654d  OpenSSL_1_0_0-stable -> origin/OpenSSL_1_0_0-stable
   76b49a8..cc74177  OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable -> origin/OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable
   c59bd61..4d9dc0c  OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable -> origin/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable
 * [new tag]         OpenSSL-fips-2_0_9 -> OpenSSL-fips-2_0_9
Updating c40dba9..e0f9bf1
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    crypto/aes/Makefile
    crypto/asn1/Makefile
    crypto/bf/Makefile
    crypto/bio/Makefile
    crypto/buffer/Makefile
    crypto/camellia/Makefile
    crypto/cast/Makefile
    crypto/cmac/Makefile
    crypto/cms/Makefile
    crypto/conf/Makefile
    crypto/des/Makefile
    crypto/dh/Makefile
    crypto/dsa/Makefile
    crypto/dso/Makefile
    crypto/ecdh/Makefile
    crypto/ecdsa/Makefile
    crypto/engine/Makefile
    crypto/err/Makefile
    crypto/evp/Makefile
    crypto/hmac/Makefile
    crypto/idea/Makefile
    crypto/lhash/Makefile
    crypto/md4/Makefile
    crypto/md5/Makefile
    crypto/mdc2/Makefile
    crypto/modes/Makefile
    crypto/ocsp/Makefile
    crypto/pem/Makefile
    crypto/pkcs12/Makefile
    crypto/pkcs7/Makefile
    crypto/pqueue/Makefile
    crypto/rand/Makefile
    crypto/rc2/Makefile
    crypto/rc4/Makefile
    crypto/ripemd/Makefile
    crypto/seed/Makefile
    crypto/sha/Makefile
    crypto/srp/Makefile
    crypto/stack/Makefile
    crypto/ts/Makefile
    crypto/txt_db/Makefile
    crypto/ui/Makefile
    crypto/whrlpool/Makefile
    crypto/x509/Makefile
    engines/Makefile
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Comment: `git clean -df && git checkout --` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git

Comment: Thanks zedfoxus. To be clear, I checkout with `git clone` and then go to work. I don't have local copies because there's only one set of sources with OpenSSL. So I work directly from the clone. Hence the reason I want to abandon changes, and not re-check things out. (Related: I think git is the wrong tool for the job here because there's only one set of sources. There's no need for the added complexity).

Comment: Hi Jeff, if you did `git clone` you got the entire remote repo locally on your system. [Git checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298598/what-is-the-difference-between-git-clone-and-checkout) does not re-clone. It switches your local copy between branches. Git is a good tool for managing OpenSSL source. More about that some other time.

Comment: If you use VS Code, there is a button for each file to discard changes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To sync back with the HEAD, it's

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 9):

To discard changes you can also use

```
git checkout -- .
```

Check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52713

Answer (score -2):

Although @Willie Wheeler answer is perfect and I have used it in the past , I have been at the receiving end mostly because this command just removes without any chance of second thoughts.

You may try 
git reset --soft

Comment: This keeps the files staged.  The OP's intent is to completely discard the changes.