# What is the purpose of "Switch To" in EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git

I am using EGit and am aware that Checkout (on the Git perspective) allows me to switch between branches already in my repository (see [What is the difference between git clone and checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298598/what-is-the-difference-between-git-clone-and-checkout) ). However there is also the option "Switch To". When I "Switch To" another branch, it appears to me that all of the files stay the same, but just the "branch label" at the top of the page changes. I am not viewing the code on the branch I have switched to, but am viewing the code from my previous branch.

So what is the purpose of "Switch To" in EGit and when would I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Switch to" is described [in the Egit manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Checking_out_an_existing_Branch) as being the `git checkout` equivalent.

The only cases it would not change / update the working tree are:

- you mistakenly chose the same branch as the current one
- or those files were private (not tracked yet), in which case Git by default would keep them.
- or the Eclipse working space somehow does not refer to the actual Git working tree.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that "Switch to" is the equivalent of checkout and the for the link to the manual.

I started a new workspace and "Switch To" now works! Not sure what was going wrong in my previous attempts but its resolved now.