# should I do a git fork then branch or just a git branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fork

I haven't done much branching work in git and branching so excuse the noob nature of this.

I'm going to start working on a feature (say 'user oauth') that I want to work in isolation and merge in at a later point. Ideally, I will be merging this into the master branch at a later point.  Obviously, I'd like to do in a separate branch. Is it general practice to just do a branch in my local instance or should I fork the repo and create a branch in the new separate folder structure. In my mind, the latter seems better in case I just want to wipe out the branch, I can just delete this other folder structure?

thx

**edit 1 per ryan**

```
git clone git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git  
git branch test-feature-branch
```

**edit 2**
wow, thx for information. It's possible that this will be a second application. Is there a way I can clone it and then essentially push it as a new repository to new github?

Comment: Please walk us through what commands you would use the latter case so we can understand what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of git cloning and branches is that making separate repos is not necessary. A fork is really just another name for a clone and as such, you can make branches for multiple features at the same time within your local clone, picking and choosing which ones to push to the remote and/or merge into other branches (or discard).

See the answers to this question for more details: [git branch, fork, fetch, merge, rebase and clone, what are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329943/difference-between-a-branch-fork-and-clone-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fork a git project. You can clone a existing one. Clone-ing is basically creating a new project starting from another one.

I would not do this when adding new functionality unless i want 2 different applications.

If adding functionally that you want it merged back into the main with git you can do:

```
git checkout -b secondBranch
```

--this will create the branch "secondBranch" and also put you in that branch immediately.
The next commit will be on this secondBranch.

If you want to delete it just do

```
git branch -d secondBranch
```

or if you decide to merge it, switch to the master /main branch and merge secondBranch into it.

```
git branch master
```

--will swith you to master

```
 git merge secondBranch
```

--at this point you will be in the master branch with the changes from secondBranch merged into the master

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely general practice to just create a branch in your local instance. When you're done, simply merge it into e.g. your master branch and push master to origin.