# Is it possible to fork a github repo that I already own and then save it as a new repository?

Tags: git, github

Another simple question on how to handle in github following up on this: [should I do a git fork then branch or just a git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742159/should-i-do-a-git-fork-then-branch-or-just-a-git-branch)

I want to use an app that I have as a private repo as the starting point for a new app. It looks like I'd want to fork it and then clone it but when I fork it, I don't see a new repo. However, the fact that I can click fork makes me believe that this is possible? How would I achieve this or is there a better way for me to do this? I was thinking of just branching but I need to work with another developer and it would seem easier to just have these as separate repos.

thx

Answer (score 3):

You can

1. create a new private repository on github,
2. then clone your current repository on github to your local machine,
3. then add that new repository to one of the remote of the clone,
4. and finally push it to the new repository.

For example, let say your current repository is `git@github.com:me/current.git` and the new one is `git@github.com:me/new.git`.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:me/current.git local-copy
$ cd local-copy
$ git remote add new-repo git@github.com:me/new.git
$ git push new-repo master
```