# Cloning a git repo that will be the upstream parent but I want to make changes to the README for my new project and not ever push that back

Tags: git, git-index

I want to base my new project off of an existing git repo.
My intention is not to extend the current project but to start a new project with different aims.
Specifically I want to remove the original README and some of the original folders and make a more generic template version of the project.

I want to be able to later push my enhancements back up stream as pull requests but my initial customisation changes such as changing the README and removing two folders specific to the original project, I dont ever want to push these changes upstream.

How would you manage this?

Comment: maybe just fork? or create branch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963878/how-do-you-fork-your-own-repository-on-github