# Is it possible to fork my own repository on GitHub?

Tags: github, fork

I'm trying to fork my own repository, every time I click fork though it just reloads my repo. The fork button is definitely there on the page.

I am using GitHub client and GitHub website, I have little knowledge of Git commands, and don't know how to run them.

I also don't want to make another branch. So the topic that "may have the answer" doesn't, as that is using branching.

I really need to fork it because I'm creating an addon for Firefox, the first step was to stylize the bookmarks bar with a theme, I did that and people are requesting I release a separate addon just with the stylizing. So I want to fork it, give it a new name and then release that.

Comment: why do you want to do that instead of making a new branch?

Comment: Because I'm making an addon [here](https://github.com/yajd/MouseMarks/) but as it is right now, its good to release as another addon. So i just want to fork this, change the name of the addon/repo some details and then submit.

Comment: @Viscocent thats something else, i don't use git I use GitHub client and GitHub website and I'm trying to not branch.

Comment: @Noitidart the linked question contains answers that don't involve branching, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9014852/456814).

Comment: Thanks @cupcake I got a similar solution from jeffjia

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742677/is-it-possible-to-fork-a-github-repo-that-i-already-own-and-then-save-it-as-a-ne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A walk-around is to create an organization first, transfer the repo to the organization, and then fork it. If you could explain more about why you want to use fork instead of branch in the scenario, there may be better answers.

--

If you just want to "copy" an existing repo. You can create a new github project, and use `git pull <reference to old repo>` in the new project directory, commit and push again. You can start modification from there.

Comment: Thank you man! I'm going to try this. I really need to fork it because I'm creating an addon for firefox called mousemarks, the first step was to stylize the bookmarks bar with a theme, I did that and people are requesting I release a seperate addon just with the stylizing. So I want to fork it, rename it "Bookmark Bar Stylized" and the nrelease that. Then continue to work on my "MouseMarks" addon.

Comment: hey man I made the org  i cant figure out how to transfer the repo tho

Comment: There is an instruction on github: https://help.github.com/articles/how-to-transfer-a-repository. Instead of using another user name, you can use your new org name. Then it works magically.

Comment: It works thanks man!! Can I transfer the repo from my org back to myself *before* renaming the forked repo? Or do i have to rename it first?

Comment: I have not tried this way. I am thinking whether github has db logic or check which prevents such actions. If you really need to do a swap, you may have to use another org. This is a bit hacky.

Comment: Hey man after transfeirng to org, i forked it, then renamed it, now when i try to transfer my repo from org back to me it says "Noitidart already has a repository in the temp-org-for-forking-my-own-repos/MouseMarks network" :(

Comment: Yeah. It seems that Github has such constraint that two projects of a single user or org cannot be the fork of the other.

Comment: There was issues with this method. I had to reach out to github support. I couldn't rename my fork in my org that i just forked to something else. and then bring the original from the temp org back to my org. so support detached them from each other. sux :(