# What is the fork and clone in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git fork is git clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286571/git-fork-is-git-clone)

Can anyone help me out to understand concept behind fork and clone?, I know what clone does but wants to more detailed information about.

Comment: Please refer to the following link, it may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329943/what-is-the-difference-between-branch-fork-fetch-merge-rebase-and-clone-in-g

Answer (score 1):

Clone checks out the entire repository for local use (with the idea that the changes will be pushed back to the master at some point), whereas forking doesn't necessarily mean that the code will get pushed back to the master. The fixes on the fork might not be accepted for merge into the master and the forked version of the project can still have development done on it, if the developer who fixes it really needs the fix.