# Go: how to add git revision to binaries built?

Tags: git, version-control, go

I want to add the current git revision number to the the binary built by `go build` so that I can do something like `./mybinary --revision` to see which revision it is built from (usually for troubleshooting later on after deployment).

Obviously I cannot put the revision number into the source since that will change the source with a new revision.

I'm wondering if there is any other way to do this?
Or do you think this is just a bad idea? If so, what's the recommended way to establish the relation between built binaries and its source version?
Version numbers do not seem to be a good idea with a distributed version control system.

Comment: Useful reading [Is it a good practice to make a tag in git for every deployment build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494637/is-it-a-good-practice-to-make-a-tag-in-git-for-every-deployment-build) [Enable ident string for Git repos](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1796675/960558) [How to auto-generate a version string in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673007/how-to-auto-generate-a-version-string-in-git)

Comment: That is a lazy answer, @LazyBadger. You are truly honoring your name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can get the git revision into $VERSION and have a variable named `version` (type string) in your main package, you can set it during the build with:

```
#!/bin/sh
VERSION=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
go build -ldflags "-X main.version=$VERSION"  myfile.go
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome.  btw, `git describe` does great things (especially if you have tags)

Comment: I am getting error while building - -X flag requires argument of the form importpath.name=value

Comment: @VivekR Thanks for the comment, I have fixed my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The normal process should no longer involve any `ldflags`, starting with Go 1.18 (Q4 2021/Q1 2022).

See [issue 37475](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37475) and [CL 356013](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/356013/2/doc/go1.18.html)

> **The `go` command now embeds version control information in binaries** including the currently checked-out revision and a flag indicating  whether edited or untracked files are present.
>
> Version control information is embedded if the `go` command is invoked in a directory within a Git or Mercurial repository, and the `main` package and its containing `main` module are in the same repository.
> This information may be omitted using the flag `-buildvcs=false`.
>
> Additionally, the `go` command embeds information about:
>
> - the build including build and tool tags (set with `-tags`),
> - compiler,
> - assembler, and
> - linker flags (like `-gcflags`),
> - whether `cgo` was enabled, and if it was, the values of the `cgo` environment variables (like `CGO_CFLAGS`).
>
> This information may be omitted using the flag `-buildinfo=false`.
>
> Both VCS and build information may be  read together with module information using:
>
> - `go version -m file` or
> - `runtime/debug.ReadBuildInfo` (for the currently running binary) or
> - the new [`debug/buildinfo` package](https://pkg.go.dev/debug/buildinfo@master).

[CL 373875](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/373875/) adds

> - The `BuildInfo` struct has new fields with additional information about how the binary was built.
> - The new `GoVersion` field holds the version of Go used to build the binary.
> - The new `Settings` field is a slice of `BuildSettings` structs holding key/value pairs describing the build.

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a `version.go` file with a single `var version string` and then process that before a call to `go build` and reset it after. In other words, go doesn't support any type of code generation so you'll need to rely on something external to do this.

Comment: This is useful to handle semantic versioning via git tags. One option to alter version.go is with sed: `sed -i 's/var Version = .*/var Version = "'$(git describe --always)'"/' path/to/version.go`

Answer (score 1):

For *all and any* versioned in Git code **most obvious way** for getting identification-string for any changeset (while I leave to you task of displaying this string on `--revision` options) is

- using (at least sporadically) tags
- [git describe](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) (with relevant options) on build stage

Answer (score 0):

You would generally use tags (also known as labels in other version control systems) to note the files that make up a particular build.  http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging.  I typically make tags that include the version and build date.  For example v1.2_29Mar2013.  If I have several products that can be built from the same code base I'll include something to identify which product.