# Git Integration-Manager Workflow

Tags: git

The book on http://www.git-scm.com website has some workflow examples with explanations:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

I need help on steps/commands for creating the Integration-Manager Workflow

[image]

Here are my confusions:

1. Create a Linux user account for each developer?
2. Create a public repo for each user in a different folder or their own home directories?
3. The Manager should SSH to the server. Check and manually pull the updates from each public repo of developer?
4. Finally the push to the "Blessed Repo" would also be manually done by the Manager after SSH login to server?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Linux user account for each developer?
- Each developer uses their own account with their own email and they upload their keys.

Create a public repo for each user in a different folder or their own home directories?
- Store your project wherever it convenient. It can be different for each person.  Wherever they store they project, that's where their .git directory will be.

The Manager should SSH to the server. Check and manually pull the updates from each public repo of developer?
- I recommend haveing them work in branches and then you can control the merges better after code review, testing, etc. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204499/631619)

Finally the push to the "Blessed Repo" would also be manually done by the Manager after SSH login to server?
- Yes

Comment: Thanks. Please can you elaborate the first point. "Each developer uses their own account with their own email and they upload their keys" You mean the git config?

Answer (score 0):

> Create a Linux user account for each developer?

In an ideal world, you don't care.

In real business world, you create a Linux user account for each developer, or you use something like [gitosis](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-7.html) to handle git authentication.

> Create a public repo for each user in a different folder or their own home directories?

In an ideal world, again, each developer has its own public repository, and you don't care where they are, as long as they let the integrator know whenever there are changes.

If you are on bussiness, though, you should have one repository for each developer, or a repository in where every developer pushes to a different branch - maybe you can force this with hooks on the server.

> The Manager should SSH to the server. Check and manually pull the updates from each public repo of developer?

Manager doesn't really need to `ssh` to the server - it depends on the git protocol you decide to use. You can use https, instead, and it would work too. He just has to have `push` access to the blessed repository, and `pull` access to the developers' repositor[y/ies].

> Finally the push to the "Blessed Repo" would also be manually done by the Manager after SSH login to server?

Again, it doesn't really matter the protocol the integrator uses. The only important thing is that he has `push` access. And, yes, it would be done manually by the integrator after testing and checking the changeset to integrate.

PS: I've just read that - for I-don't-know-what reason -, they've deprecated gitosis in favor of [`gitolite`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Gitolite).

Comment: Thanks. Please add commands like how to create public repo for each using on Server with required permissions and SSH access only to their repo.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar well, you have installation instructions for `gitosis` and `gitolite` in the provided links of the `Pro Git`...