# How to use git ? git-commit ? git-push?

Tags: git, commit, git-push, git-commit

I am working on a website, and I need to use Git for practical reasons.
However, I think I have not totally understood how it works.

I want to do something quite simple, and I am working on localhost. I make several changes, and sometimes I use Git for put the new or modify files on the server.

Edit²:
after reading some docs, I have reinit all my git repositories. I really understand nothing to git.
So, I connect to my server, and I commit the files. After I reinit my local repository. I add my remote and I did `git pull carpe master` (carpe is my alias for the remote server).
If I do git checkout master on local, I see all the paths from the tracked files from the server. But git did not download the files to the working tree...
I really do not understand. What should I do for getting the file in my local working tree ?

Answer (score 2):

By pushing, you've sent your commits to the remote git repository at `ssh://user@myname.my/mypath/.git`.  However, the content of this repository is independent to what your Web server is serving -- the HTML you see in your browser (this is known as the *working copy*).  What you need to do now is to pull the changes from the repository into the server's working copy (`git pull origin`).

It's really worth putting in the time to go through a decent git tutorial, as others have suggested.  My personal favorite is http://gitimmersion.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You have just pushed your changes from the local master branch to the remote master branch. (ie sent your changes to the remote server.)

Have a look [here](http://git-scm.com/book) for a descent introduction to git

Comment: So I have read the doc. I feel me more lost than before ...
So I have removed all my back git configuration. I init git on the server. I commit. Then I created a remot on local and i pulled him.
But the files are still not writing. I mean i have done `git pull carpe master` It should put all my files at the same versions than the master branch on the remote server ? But files arent downloading and git answers me : `already up to date`
...

Comment: If I do `git checkout master` I see all the file who come from the internet remote. But I see only their path, et they are not written into the working tree.

How can I ask to git to check and download file from master branch to working tree ?

Comment: There are two repositories, yours and the remote. When you do a pull you take all the changes from the remote and apply them to yours. When you do a push you send your changes to the remote server. Checkout master just makes your local repo use the master branch

Answer (score 0):

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204499/631619

I think the key things to know are:

tracking branches & 'origin'.  Understanding this is key.  It's the inbetween part of how changes flow to and from remote servers and local environments.