# Cannot pull/push my git repository anymore. "Merge conflicts"

Tags: git, repository

I have made changes to my project repository in several files. Then i commited and didn't pushed em. Later i've found a bug in code and opened git log to revert the last commit. Since i did it this commit has *disappeared* from log, and i cannot both push or pull repository due to an error.

I've tried making a new commit but this only changed the error message on pull/push:

> An error was raised by libgit2. Category = 21 (MergeConflict). 5
>   uncommitted changes would be overwritten by merge

`git status` message:

> On branch master
>
> Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 1 and 1
>   different commit each, respectively.   (use "git pull" to merge the
>   remote branch into yours)

Commited from VS 2013, using log from TortoiseGit.
What happend and how do i push/pull and get back my bugged commit changes?

Comment: Which command did you use for removing the last commit?  What output gives "git status"?

Comment: Using "revision graph" i've found my commit in /master log, but if i try to `merge to "master"` i get the same error.

Comment: Can you try a git pull --rebase first, then a git push?

Comment: @VonC seems like that's what has helped. Or not that. Not so expirienced with git yet, especially the console

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204499/631619 helpful in understanding what's is really going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.

To resolve that "divergence", you can do a:

```
git pull --rebase
git push
```

That will replay your commits on top of the most recent `origin/master` ones, and allows the push to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

In tortoisegit, i had to use command **Reset "master" to this** on last commit.
Found it in `TortoiseGit > Revision Graph`.