# `git fetch` a remote branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-fetch

The remote repository contains various branches such as `origin/daves_branch`:

```
$ git branch -r
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/daves_branch
origin/master
```

How do I switch to `daves_branch` in the local repository so that it tracks `origin/daves_branch`?

I tried:

```
$ git fetch origin daves_branch
$ git checkout daves_branch
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [git checkout remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/git-checkout-remote-branch)

Comment: I used:  
`git fetch --all`,
Then to view all the branches: `git branch`,
Then I checkout the branch: `git checkout nameofnewbranch`

Comment: check your question ans
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072261/push-and-pull-branches-in-git/47780374#47780374](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072261/push-and-pull-branches-in-git/47780374#47780374)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: `git fetch origin discover:discover && git checkout discover`

Comment: David, can you edit your question's title and make it clear as a standalone?e

Comment: "Git fetch remote branch" <-- this isn't a question. Make it become a question

Comment: Interestingly, the question headline answers the question itself: `git fetch <remote> <branch>` is the correct syntax.

Comment: This works for me git fetch origin daves_branch

Answer (score 4231, accepted):

## Update: Using Git Switch

All of the information written below was accurate, but a new command, [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) has been added that simplifies the effort.

If `daves_branch` exists on the remote repository, but not on your local branch, you can simply type:

```sh
git switch daves_branch
```

Since you do not have the branch locally, this will automatically make `switch` look on the remote repo.  It will then also automatically set up remote branch tracking.

Note that if `daves_branch` doesn't exist locally you'll need to `git fetch` first before using `switch`.

---

## Original Post

You need to create a local branch that tracks a remote branch. The following command will create a local branch named **daves_branch**, tracking the remote branch **origin/daves_branch**. When you push your changes the remote branch will be updated.

For most recent versions of Git:

```
git checkout --track origin/daves_branch
```

`--track` is shorthand for `git checkout -b [branch] [remotename]/[branch]` where [remotename] is **origin** in this case and [branch] is twice the same, **daves_branch** in this case.

For Git 1.5.6.5 you needed this:

```
git checkout --track -b daves_branch origin/daves_branch
```

For Git 1.7.2.3 and higher, this is enough (it might have started earlier, but this is the earliest confirmation I could find quickly):

```
git checkout daves_branch
```

Note that with recent Git versions, this command will not create a local branch and will put you in a 'detached HEAD' state. If you want a local branch, use the `--track` option.

Full details are here: *[3.5 Git Branching - Remote Branches, Tracking Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches)*

Comment: Does this need to be proceeded with a git fetch discover?

Comment: Git fetch is only needed if something has changed on the remote, e.g. if Dave has pushed a branch to the main repo and your repo doesn't yet have any references to it.

Comment: Which is actually true in this instance.

Comment: "git fetch" to make sure your repo is updated with remote references and "git checkout --track origin/discover" should be enough. Then you can commit to that branch and a "git push" to sync the remote with your changes.

Comment: I tried this and got "fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches. Did you intend to checkout 'upstream/develop' which can not be resolved as commit?". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @NeilBarnwell As Magnus said, do a `git fetch`

Comment: @NeilBarnwell I needed to do a `git fetch --all` (which fetches all remotes) to get this to work.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell Read this answer [how to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320930/18788)

Comment: @NeilBarnwell this worked for me: `git remote show origin` `git remote update` (explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945654/git-checkout-on-a-remote-branch-does-not-work)

Comment: `fatal: cannot update paths and switch to branch '...' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/...' which can not be resolved as commit?`
???

Comment: Looks like git 1.5.6.5 needs this instead:

git checkout --track -b origin/daves_branch

Comment: I ran into `warning: refname 'origin/<branch>' is ambigious`.  The fix for me was to instead run `git checkout --track remotes/origin/<branch>`

Comment: This made a mess for me, it created a local branch named origin/<branch> which is now ambiguous to the remote branch origin/<branch> and I don't know how to get rid of the crazy local branch!

Comment: Yeah I would not use this command. It may be because I have multiple remotes in my config, but I am now in the same boat as 'Alan Moore'. I just deleted the local repo and then cloned it from GitHub again... But before I did that, I was having a hard time undoing whatever the above command did. Even after `$ git branch -d origin/mybranch`...

Comment: You need to add the local branch name explicitly, otherwise git creates a new local branch with the full branch path, as @AlanMoore and @derekmx271 stated above: `git checkout -b --track daves_branch origin/daves_branch`

Comment: @MikeScott `git checkout --track -b daves_branch origin/daves_branch`, otherwise it tells me _--track is not a valid branch_.

Comment: You do need to do `git fetch` first if the branch is not present locally.

Comment: @Mike Scott Regarding "`You need to create a local branch that tracks a remote branch`". Does it matter what name is given to the local branch or should it match that of the remote repo's?

Comment: `git fetch origin mybranch` neither showed any error, nor did it show mybranch in branch list with `git branch -v` .. And then doing `git checkout mybranch` had no effect. So I tried, `git checkout --track origin/mybranch`, and it worked! Thanks @ralphtheninja

Comment: Can this be done to create local versions of all remote branches, without specifying each individually?

Answer (score 1290):

I have used [`fetch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) followed by [`checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html)...

```
git fetch <remote> <rbranch>:<lbranch>
git checkout <lbranch>
```

...where `<rbranch>` is the remote branch or *source ref* and `<lbranch>` is the as yet **non-existent** local branch or *destination ref* you want to track and which you probably want to name the same as the remote branch or source ref. This is explained under [options](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html#_options) in the explanation of `<refspec>`.

**Bash is so smart it auto completes the first command if I *tab* after the first few letters of the remote branch. That is, I don't even have to name the local branch; Bash automatically copies the name of the remote branch for me. Thanks, Bash!**

Also as [the answer in this similar Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783426/1020470) shows, if you don't name the local branch in `fetch`, you can still create it when you check it out by using the `-b` flag. *That is,* `git fetch <remote> <branch>` followed by `git checkout -b <branch> <remote>/<branch>` does exactly the same as my initial answer. And evidently, if your repository has *only one* remote, then you can just do `git checkout <branch>` after `fetch` and it will create a local branch for you. *For example,* you just cloned a repository and want to check out additional branches from the remote.

I believe that some of the documentation for `fetch` may have been copied verbatim from [`pull`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html). In particular the section on `<refspec>` in [options](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html#_options) is the same. However, I do not believe that `fetch` will ever [`merge`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html), so that if you leave the destination side of the colon empty, `fetch` **should do nothing**.

NOTE: `git fetch <remote> <refspec>` is short for `git fetch <remote> <refspec>:` which would therefore do nothing, but `git fetch <remote> <tag>` is the same as `git fetch <remote> <tag>:<tag>` which should copy the remote `<tag>` locally.

I guess this is only helpful if you want to copy a remote branch locally, but not necessarily check it out right away. Otherwise, I now would use [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9537923/1020470), which is explained in detail in the first section of the [checkout description](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html#_description) and later in the [options](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html#_options) section under the explanation of `--track`, since it's a one-liner. *Well...* sort of a one-liner, because you would *still* have to run `git fetch <remote>` first.

FYI: The order of the `<refspecs>` (source:destination) explains the bizarre pre Git 1.7 method for [deleting remote branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Deleting-Remote-Branches). That is, push nothing into the destination refspec.

Comment: Yes for git commands to be auto-completed then [git-completion.bash](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) must be enabled. Directions "to use these routines" is included at the top of the source file. You may also wish to use [git-prompt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) as well (directions included in source). Note on a Macintosh, `~/.bashrc` is `~/.bash-profile`. During Git installation on Macintosh, these two files are not included, and the `.bash-profile` file in `$HOME` is not altered to add theses commands.

Comment: This worked for me to get the remote code into a local branch. It did not however get my local branch to track the remote branch.

Comment: And approve that switched to branch that you want to be in `git branch`.

Comment: For some reason, `git fetch remote branch` didn't add a branch head at all for me, though all the refs got fetched, so when I tried to follow the steps in the accepted answer, I got the error that `pathspec did not match any file(s) known to git.`, but the `rbranch:lbranch` approach worked. Interestingly, it also fetched all the tags that started with the same prefix, like it is a wildcard (`rbranch*`).

Comment: Nit: git doesn't do the autocompleting, it is the bash shell that is doing it.

Comment: This really helped me - I simply wanted to fetch a remote branch that my colleague had added to the origin.  A lot of documentation seems to me to be missing the critical piece about adding the name of the new local branch that you want the fetch to be directed to - `<rbranch>:<lbranch>`.  Thank you very much.

Comment: FWIW, I think the difference between this answer and the accepted answer is that this one tells you to do the `fetch` command.  It the accepted answer makes sense though because OP notes that he already did the fetch.  That's at least the issue I ran into.

Comment: This is perfect for tracking a remote branch of a repo you've previously forked (e.g. tracking the dev branch of an OSS project you contribute to). Thanks!

Comment: This specific approach has the added benefit of only retrieving the desired branch (rather than all remote branch references), this was important for me on a slow connection interfacing with a rather large repo.

Comment: I just did `git fetch origin <remoteBranch>` now how can I locally check that branch out? NeverMind. I figured it out. I can simply do `git checkout <remoteBranch>` and it will just create a local branch with the name of `<remoteBranch>`. I'm just not so sure how I should process that. I wrote a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464499/how-does-git-checkout-work-after-git-fetch) if you can answer...

Comment: Hi @Honey, as the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16095458/1020470) states: "And evidently if your repo has only one remote, then you can just do git checkout <branch> after fetch and it will create a local branch for you. EG: You just cloned a repo and want to check out additional branches from the remote." Also in the [git-checkout docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout): "If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to: `$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`"

Comment: This also works with partial clones: Example: `git fetch --depth=20 <remote> <rbranch>:<lbranch>`

Comment: i get `fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/fuse_keybindings-setborderpx-alphabar-transparency-monrules-nowarpresize of non-bare repository`

Comment: @Fuseteam is it possible you are trying to update the branch that you're already on? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236743/git-refusing-to-fetch-into-current-branch. Try to create a remote first: `git remote add FOO url/of/repo` then fetch the branch from the remote: `git fetch FOO fuse_keybindings...`. This may create a new local branch or update the existing local branch depending. See [the git-fetch docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) & good luck!

Comment: hi @MarkMikofski i am trying to fetch a remote branch to have it locally, I have already added the remote, and I tried `git fetch --all` to  no avail. i can't remember if I tried `git fetch remote-name branch` thanks for the tip

Comment: had to do `--update-head-ok` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/19205680/13070032

Answer (score 498):

If you are trying to "checkout" a new remote branch (that exists only on the remote, but not locally), here's what you'll need:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout --track origin/<remote_branch_name>
```

This assumes you want to fetch from *origin*. If not, replace *origin* by your *remote* name.

Comment: Usually, I use git fetch,  but the thing is what is the difference between git fetch and git fetch origin ?

Comment: @PingWoo Assuming that the branch you want to fetch resides in _origin_ remote, both `git fetch` and `git fetch remote` will do the same thing. If you need to fetch from a remote other than `origin`, you could do that using `git fetch <other_remote_name>`. This situation is highly uncommon, just mentioned here for completeness.

Comment: i get `fatal: 'fusedwm/fuse_keybindings-setborderpx-alphabar-transparency-monrules-nowarpresize' is not a commit and a branch 'fuse_keybindings-setborderpx-alphabar-transparency-monrules-nowarpresize' cannot be created from it`

Answer (score 211):

fetch the branch locally:

```
git fetch origin <branchName>
```

move to that branch:

```
git checkout <branchName>
```

Comment: Does not bring other branches

Comment: @BenjaminHarel the question says "fetch a remote branch" not all branches. for that follow this may be helpfull for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches

Comment: After using this `fetch` command required branch will be available on local machine.
`git checkout -b 'your_branch' origin/'remote branch'` is required to checkout this branch.

Comment: I wish people would post more simple answers like this. Thank you for getting to the point, I'm pretty sure I google this about once every month.

Answer (score 168):

To checkout myBranch that exists remotely and not a locally - This worked for me:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout myBranch
```

I got this message:

```
Branch myBranch set up to track remote branch myBranch from origin
Switched to a new branch 'myBranch'
```

Comment: In other words you don't have to write `-t`?

Comment: I think there's an error in this answer. I originally did the command without `-t` and got `You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.` because there wasn't a local branch of the same name. I had to re-run with `-t` to fix.

Comment: This worked well for me - my colleague had added a new remote branch that I wanted to add to my local repo.  I kept fetching but didn't see the new branch appearing locally.  Didn't realize that I could just run `checkout` for it to create it.  Thanks!

Comment: depends on git versions. Latest version, as said elsewhere here, only needs git checkout <name of branch on origin>. BE CAREFUL WITH SAME-NAME LOCAL vs REMOTE BRANCHES - they will mess stuff up

Comment: `--all` is never a good idea, because it will download every file on every branch. It will take more time and space. It's better to be specific with the branch name and do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16095458/5175709)

Answer (score 93):

Use `git branch -a` (both local and remote branches) or `git branch -r` (only remote branches) to see all the remotes and their branches. You can then do a `git checkout -t remotes/repo/branch` to the remote and create a local branch.

There is also a [git-ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) command to see all the refs and tags for that remote.

Comment: `git checkout remotes/repo/branch` makes git checkout look for a pathspec, not a remote repo.

Comment: Yes, is it even possible to checkout a branch on the remote repo? Obviously (or maybe it wasn't so obvious), remotes are first fetched so that you have them locally. The git book has a good section on them: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: `git checkout -t remote_branch_name` is probably the most simple and laziest way out of all answers.

Answer (score 57):

To fetch a branch that exists on remote, the simplest way is:

```
git fetch origin branchName
git checkout branchName
```

You can see if it already exists on remote with:

```
git branch -r
```

This will fetch the remote branch to your local and will automatically track the remote one.

Comment: How does this question not have more upvotes? I could be wrong but this sure seemed to do the trick, fetched a branch I didn't have on local from remote...

Answer (score 54):

**The title and the question are confused:**

- Git fetch remote branch
- how can my colleague pull that branch specifically.

If the question is, *how can I get a remote branch to work with, or how can I Git checkout a remote branch?*, a simpler solution is:

With Git (>= 1.6.6) you are able to use:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

If local `<branch_name>` is not found, but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote with a matching name, treat it as equivalent to:

```
git checkout -b <branch_name> --track <remote>/<branch_name>
```

[See documentation for Git checkout](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html)

For your friend:

```
$ git checkout discover
Branch discover set up to track remote branch discover
Switched to a new branch 'discover'
```

Comment: Thanks Guillaume! I just used this command and wrote a post about it to depict my exact case: http://www.leniel.net/2014/05/checkout-git-remote-origin-branch-not-master-to-a-local-tracking-branch.html

Comment: <!-- git checkout <remote-branch-name> --> works as expected, Thanks Guillaume!

Answer (score 37):

Use:

```
git checkout -b serverfix origin/serverfix
```

This is a common enough operation that Git provides the [`--track`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---track) shorthand:

```
git checkout --track origin/serverfix
```

In fact, this is so common that there’s even a shortcut for that shortcut. If the branch name you’re trying to checkout (a) doesn’t exist and (b) exactly matches a name on only one remote, Git will create a tracking branch for you:

```
git checkout serverfix
```

To set up a local branch with a different name than the remote branch, you can easily use the first version with a different local branch name:

```
git checkout -b sf origin/serverfix
```

Now, your local branch `sf` will automatically pull from `origin/serverfix`.

Source: [*Pro Git, 2nd Edition*, written by Scott Chacon and Ben Straub](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches) (cut for readability)

Comment: Those shorthands were a lesson

Comment: why you miss git fetch origin serverfix?

Answer (score 35):

## [Quick Answer]

There are many alternatives, and my favourites are:

**- Alternative 1:**

```
git fetch --all
git checkout YourBranch
```

> Using this alternative using a branch that exist remotely, but not in your local.

**- Alternative 2:**

```
git checkout -b 'YourBranch' origin/'YourRemote'
```

> Probably, this is the simplest way.

Answer (score 32):

With this simple command:

```
git checkout -b 'your_branch' origin/'remote branch'
```

Answer (score 22):

What helped me was

1. To view all available remote branches (e.g. 'remote-branch-name')

   git branch -r
2. Create a local branch using remote branch name

```bash
git fetch && git checkout 'remote-branch-name'
```

Comment: What happens when you run the command ```git push``` without any other arguments?  Is the local branch named ```remote-branch-name``` automatically associated with (tracking to) the remote branch named ```origin/remote-branch-name```.  Or do you need to run ```git push -u origin remote-branch-name```

Comment: this will cause HEAD detached state

Answer (score 16):

```
git fetch

git branch -r

git checkout <branch_name>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 15):

You can fetch and checkout the remote branch in one shot too:

```
git fetch && git checkout the-branch-name
```

Answer (score 15):

Simply try:

```
git pull origin your_branch_name
```

Comment: Rizo, git pull origin branch_name should be the best solution. You are the only person that posted this as a solution and it worked for me. This works because it will update your branch with the master branch. simple and uncomplicated.

Comment: the problem with this is that it will try to merge that remote branch with your CURRENT branch, which is not the remote one (since that is new for your local repo)

Comment: This will merge to your current branch.

Answer (score 14):

I typed

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

and got

```
Branch <branch_name> set up to track remote branch <branch_name> from origin.
Switched to a new branch '<branch_name>'
```

Comment: from git checkout documentation: If <branch_name> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote with a matching name, treat as equivalent to: `git checkout -b <branch_name> --track <remote>/<branch_name>`

Answer (score 13):

The steps are as follows;

1. `git fetch origin` or `git fetch --all` , this will fetch all the remote branches to your local and then this the second option you can proced with.
2. `git checkout --track origin/<The_remote_branch you want to switch over>`

Then work on this branch and you can verify whether you are on that branch or not by  typing

```
git branch
```

It displayes the branch you currently in.

Answer (score 13):

At times you are asked not to fiddle with the master branch and work only the remote branch (as I was asked to). So all you need is the remote branch.

So to clone the remote branch alone (without the master), do this

```
git clone url --branch remote_branch_name
```

where,
remote_branch_name is the name of the remote branch

For example,

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git --branch v3.15
```

This will make sure that you clone the remote branch to your local branch with the name of the remote branch.

Now if you commit your code and push, the code will be submitted to that branch alone.

Comment: Related: *[How do I clone a single branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088)* - *"git 1.7.10 (April 2012) actually allows you to clone only one branch:"*

Answer (score 12):

If you would like to fetch all remote branches, please type just:

```
git fetch --all
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have a repository that was cloned with `--depth 1` then many of the commands that were listed will not work. For example, see here

```
% git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/repo/code
Cloning into 'code'...
cd code
remote: Counting objects: 1778, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1105/1105), done.
remote: Total 1778 (delta 87), reused 1390 (delta 58), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1778/1778), 5.54 MiB | 4.33 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (87/87), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (1215/1215), done.
% cd code
% git checkout other_branch
error: pathspec 'other_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
% git fetch origin other_branch
remote: Counting objects: 47289, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15906/15906), done.
remote: Total 47289 (delta 30151), reused 46699 (delta 29570), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (47289/47289), 31.03 MiB | 5.70 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (30151/30151), completed with 362 local objects.
From https://github.com/repo/code
 * branch            other_branch-> FETCH_HEAD
% git checkout other_branch
error: pathspec 'other_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
%
```

In this case I would reclone the repository, but perhaps there are other techniques e.g. *[git shallow clone (clone --depth) misses remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708231/git-shallow-clone-clone-depth-misses-remote-branches)*

Answer (score 10):

Check your `.git/config` file, particularly what tracking is present on **fetch** for that remote.

```
[remote "randomRemote"]
    url = git@github.com:someUser/someRepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/randomRemote/*
```

If it has `heads/*` pointing to `randomRemote/*`, when you run `git fetch randomRemote`, it will fetch all branches.

Then you can just checkout that branch.

Otherwise,

1. You need to add remote branches to the tracking using this. Check your `.git/config` after running this. You will understand.

   ```
   git remote set-branches --add randomRemote randomBranch
   ```
2. Run `git fetch randomRemote`. This will fetch the remote branch.
3. Now you can run `git checkout randomBranch`.

Answer (score 10):

Let's say that your remote is git@xyz.git and you want its random_branch branch. The process should be as follows:

1. First check the list of your remotes by

   > `git remote -v`
2. If you don't have the git@xyz.git remote in the above command's output, you would add it by

   > `git remote add xyz git@xyz.git`
3. Now you can fetch the contents of that remote by

   > `git fetch xyz`
4. Now checkout the branch of that remote by

   > `git checkout -b my_copy_random_branch xyz/random_branch`
5. Check the branch list by

   > `git branch -a`

The local branch my_copy_random_branch would be tracking the random_branch branch of your remote.

Answer (score 8):

`git fetch --all & git checkout <branch name>`

Answer (score 8):

`git fetch && git checkout <your friend's branch name>` should do the trick

Answer (score 7):

I want to give you one-liner command for **fetching all the remote branches to your local** and switch to your desired newly created local branch:

```
git fetch && git checkout discover
```

After running the above command you will get the below message:

```
Switched to a new branch 'discover'
Branch discover set up to track remote branch discover from origin.
```

The first line states that switched to a
***new branch*** - why new? It is already there in remote!

But actually you have to create it locally too. The branch is taken from the remote index and created locally for you.

Here `discover` is a new branch which were created from your repository's remote branch `discover`.

But the **second line** gives more information than the first one which tell us that:

Our branch is set up to **track remote branch** with the same name.

Although `git fetch` **fetches all branches** to local. But if you run `git branch` after it, you will see only `master` branch in local. **Why**?

Because for every branch you have in remote you have to create it locally too, for tracking it as `git checkout <branchname>` as we have done in the above example.

After running `git checkout` command you can run `git branch`, and now you can see both the branch:

1. master and 2. discover in your local listing.

Answer (score 3):

If you already know your remote branch like so...

```
git remote
=> One
=> Two
```

and you know the branch name you wish to checkout, for example, **br1.2.3.4**, then do

```
git fetch One
=> returns all meta data of remote, that is, the branch name in question.
```

All that is left is to checkout the branch

```
git checkout br.1.2.3.4
```

Then make any new branches off of it.

Answer (score 3):

`git branch <name> --track origin/<name>`

Answer (score 1):

You use 'git pull' to keep your branches separate. I will use the actual repository and branch names to help since 'lbranch' and 'rbranch' are tough to decipher.

Let's use:

myteam.unfuddle.com = the remote Git server

tlc = Unfuddle project account where the repository  exists

daves_branch = remote branch name

You, or any colleague, can run this to pull only your branch, no matter how many branches there are:

```
git init
git pull git@myteam.unfuddle.com:myteam/tlc daves_branch:refs/remotes/origin/daves_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple command, `git checkout remote_branch_name` will help you to create a local branch that has all the changes in the remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the repository with `git clone <repo_url> -b <branch>` (only cloning certaing branch), you should modify the `<repo_name>/.git/config` file.
Replace or modify the line that references the fetch target of the `[remote "origin"]` section to let the command `git fetch --all` discover all branches:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = <repo_git_url>
        fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Be sure to set the fetch parameter point to `/heads/master`.

Care with `git fetch --all` because this will fetch all, so may take a long time.

Answer (score -2):

```
git checkout -b branch_name
git pull remote_name branch_name
```

Comment: While this snippet might answer the question, it's better to include some explanation about what it does and how it differs from the very large number of answers already here.

Comment: I personally do not like this option. Because in case you are creating a new branch from Master and then pulling data from remote branch, that remote branch may or may not be on the same page as the master and might invite some unnecessary code updates

Comment: Some explanation would be in order.