# GIT pulling or cloning repository only gets Master branch

Tags: git, clone, bitbucket, pull

I host on BitBucket when I `git clone` a repository or use `git pull origin master` and `git pull origin myBranch` it does pull second time, but when I list branches with `git branch -v` I only see **master**. Doing `git status` shows nothing too.

How do I pull all of the branches off the web repo to my local repo?

Could it be that it's because I changed computers and name on the git settings changed so it only lets me get `master` since it's the default branch and the other one can be only accessed by whoever created it?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### The branches do exist but you can't see them

Try using this:

```
git branch -a
```

You'll now see the list of remote branches in `origin` e.g.

Output:

```
remotes/origin/tk_removes_call_centers
remotes/origin/tk_warm_transfer_fix
remotes/origin/update_README
```

and you can then

```
git checkout [any_individual_branch_name]
```

You can also get the same list with `git branch -v --all` which includes the most recent commit info, i.e.

```
git branch -v --all
```

output:

```
remotes/origin/tk_removes_call_centers     1478b14 re-adding call feedback workers
remotes/origin/tk_warm_transfer_fix        94720c5 handling blank auto policy
remotes/origin/update_README               a769b82 Update README
```

`git branch -v` (without `--all`) only shows branches you've worked on.
When you use `--all` you see *all* the tracking branches in `origin/`

Related:

- [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699/631619)
- [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch?rq=1)
- [Git fetch remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9537392/631619)
- [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1783405/631619)

Comment: You can also use the short form: ``git branch -a``

Comment: Branch mybranch set up to track remote branch mybranch from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'mybranch'

what that message means

Comment: @DonBranson thanks I added that plus what the difference is

Comment: But why is this happening?

Comment: By design.  "only shows branches you've worked on (created locally)". to show only relevant information, for example 3 branches you've used and not 300 branches you have never used.

Answer (score 1):

Do this list of commands:

**git branch -a** :

you will see the list of remote branches

**git remote show origin**

It will display all branches known by your local repository. If the branch you want to use is not in the list, run the command

**git remote update**

which updates the entire list of remote branches tracked by your local repository and then run

**git fetch**

which updates all tracked branches.

Then you can create your branch with the following checkout command:

**git checkout -b your_branch_local_name origin/your_branch_remote_name**