# What is the standard way to create a local branch from a central repo?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

Let's say that the central repo has `master`, `branch_A` and `branch_B`.
In my local working space, I have only `master` and `branch_A`.

I want to get a local branch `branch_B` in my work-space in a clean way.

i.e. I want to get the same exact contents from central repo's `branch_B` and nothing else.

I thought that `git checkout -b my_name/branch_B` would do this.
However, when I did this, I got a lot of conflicts, which I do not know why.

I do not want to resolve conflicts manually. All I want is to get the same exact contents from the central repo's `branch_B` and nothing else (i.e. discard any local changes if there is any)

Comment: `git checkout -b my_name/branch_B` creates a new branch from your current one. It doesn't have anything to do with the `branch_B` on the origin.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Then what is the *correct* command? Is it simply `git checkout branch_B`?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Comment: But you need to `git fetch` first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git fetch remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch)

Comment: Thanks for picking my answer, but you should really consider marking @torek's answer instead, it's much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is just `git checkout branch_B` *even though `branch_B` does not exist*.  In fact, it's critical that it not exist, otherwise `git checkout` can't create it.

---

Before you just use that, though, take a moment to consider this: you're not really "creating a branch from a central repo" at all.  You *can't*: you can only operate on *your own repository*.

This might seem like a distinction without a difference, but it's critical to making any sense out of numerous bits of Git weirdness.  *Everything you do, you do to, or in, **your own** repository.*

(The one thing that's sort of an exception—but not really—is `git push`.  Here, you take things you have already done to/in your own repository, and offer them to another Git, which has *its* own repository, and then request that it do things to *its* repository based on what you have offered.  It's up to *that* Git to do those things, to its own repository.)

#### Centralized repositories

When dealing with a central repository, the way you get stuff *from* them is to use `git fetch`.  The `fetch` command calls up their Git and requests, from them, a list of their branch-names and other such references, which gives your Git their branch tip commit IDs (SHA-1 hashes).  Your Git then requests any commit objects, by hash ID, and any other objects (files, or technically *"blobs"*, tree objects, earlier commits and their trees and blobs, and annotated-tag objects) needed to complete the fetch.  Your Git then squirrels all those objects away in *your* repository, and as a last step, *renames* all their branch-names to new names that your Git guarantees will not conflict with any of your branch names.

The new names your Git synthesizes from their names are your *remote-tracking branches* (`origin/master` and so on).  These are created and updated by `git fetch`.  If you use `--prune`, or set up pruning as the default, your `git fetch` operations will remove from *your* repository any remote-tracking branch names you have that no longer have a corresponding regular branch in that other Git.  (This is sometimes useful, but is not the default, probably for historical reasons plus the "only useful if there's a lot of branch creation and deletion in the other repo" aspect.)

The `origin` part of `origin/master` is just the name of the *remote*.  A remote is just a name—usually `origin`, in fact, since that's the default created by `git clone`—under which your Git stores the URL used for `git fetch`.  The name for these remote-tracking branches is constructed by putting the name of the remote in front of the remote's branch-name: hence `master` becomes `origin/master`, `branch_A` becomes `origin/branch_A`, and so on.

#### Why `git checkout` creates branches

The long form of the command you want is:

```
git checkout -b branch_B --track origin/branch_B
```

(assuming your other, central, repository is filed away under `origin`).  The `-b` here means "create a branch", and the `--track` means: "I'm going to supply another name that I want you, my Git, to look up in my repository to find a commit hash ID.  When I do that, I also want you to do the equivalent of `git branch --set-upstream-to` once the branch is made."  Last, of course, `origin/branch_B` is the name of the (already-existing) remote-tracking branch.

This gets used a lot, so the Git folks decided to have `git checkout` be extra clever: if you ask Git to check out a branch by name, *and* it doesn't exist, `git checkout` looks to see if there's some remote-tracking branch with the *same* name, after stripping the remote off the remote-tracking branch name.  (Whew!)  That is, if you `git checkout sneeze`, your Git looks to see if there's an `origin/sneeze` or maybe an `upstream/sneeze` or whatever.

*If* there's exactly one such remote-tracking branch, *then* `git checkout` is instructed to *create* a local branch, using the remote-tracking branch's current hash ID as its starting point.

#### But the shortcut really has to be spelled exactly that way

Note that `git checkout -b branch_B` doesn't make a new `branch_B` starting from `origin/branch_B`.  It just creates a new `branch_B` starting from the *current commit*.  The new branch is also *not* set up to track any remote-tracking branch.  This is because `-b` tells `git checkout` to create the branch immediately, so that it never triggers the "hey, wait, I don't have an existing `branch_B` ... maybe I should run some automatic special-case code instead?" code.

Of course, for the special case code to work, you must *have* `origin/branch_B` in your repository.  It won't reach out and find it on the centralized repository.  Only `git fetch` will do that—it's just `git fetch` and `git push` that actually call up another Git, using the URL stashed under the remote's name.

(In fact, `git remote` will also sometimes call up another Git, but that's for other SO questions.)

Comment: Wow, that was a lot of typing! :) Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute:

```
git checkout -b branch_B origin/branch_B
```

"origin" is the default name for your remote repository. To know the correct name execute:

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 0):

## First `git fetch`

After a `git fetch` your local repo should have fetched all the branches from the central repo, which usually is called `origin`.

This will have created a local remote-tracking branch called `origin/branch_B`:

```
$ git fetch
 * [new branch]      branch_B -> origin/branch_B
```

This remote-tracking branch `origin/branch_B` tracks *in your repo* what are the latest changes fetched from central repo.

You're not supposed to commit to it, so you need to create an actual branch to work on.

---

## Then `git checkout branch_B`

Then simply `git checkout branch_B` should create a local `branch_B` that automatically tracks `origin/branch_B`:

```
$ git checkout branch_B
Branch branch_B set up to track remote branch branch_B from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'branch_B'
```

---

If you want to list both your local and your remote branches, you can use `git branch -va`.