# How do I update my local branch of forked repo

Tags: git, github, git-branch

How do I update my branch of my forked repo with the current changes in the `master` of the main repo.
The scenario is I have forked a repo(say `A`) and also cloned it in my machine. Now I created a branch(say `xyz`) and created a PR in the original repo. Now it's been a while and the original repo is way ahead in commits. Now I wish to update my branch(`xyz`) with the latest changes in that file.

I updated my local by creating an upstream, fetching and pulling it. This worked for the master branch. But if I do the same with `xyz` it says:

`fatal: Couldn't find remote ref xyz`.

I am not able to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked for the master of your forked project. On your branch `xyz`, you can do :

```
git pull origin master
```

If you try pulling the from the remote, it might fail since there is no link between the branch you created(`xyz`) on the forked project and the original project.

> Couldn't find remote ref xyz

states the same message anyway. In order to fetch some remote branch to your local branch, you should follow the syntax:

```
git fetch <remote> <rbranch>:<lbranch>
```

as explained by @Mark [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16095458/1746118)

Comment: but `origin` points to the address of my forked repo in github, where I haven't made the changes.
So if I `pull` as you said it will pull changes of my forked repo in github(which is way behind the original repo)

Comment: Then add a remote for the original repo `git remote add originalrepo <URL>`, and pull/fetch from that.