# GIT: Can't checkout out branch

Tags: git

Quick question. A colleague has pushed a branch using sourcetree and named it `task/something/something_else`

Using git in a bash shell, I've done `git fetch` but am unable to check it out. I get the following error:

`error: pathspec 'task/something/something_else' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

How can I fix this?

Comment: See if this helps: [Git fetch remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git fetch remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I had a feeling the problem is caused by having 2 "/" in the branch name. Does that make sense?

Comment: What was the exact command you ran to get this error? Two slashes shouldn't be the cause.

Comment: this is an existing repo i've been using for a while. 
`git fetch` followed by
`git checkout task/something/something_else`

Comment: Try `git checkout --track origin/task/something/something_else`?

Comment: So I  tried that and get: `fatal: A branch named 'task/something' already exists` . It looks like there is a branch called task/something as well.

Comment: @wrdeman You can specify a different name for the local branch to avoid the collision – `git checkout -b something_else origin/task/something/something_else`. –– Refs (branches, tags, etc.) are stored on disk, under the `.git` directory, as `file`, `folder/file`, `folder/folder/file`, etc. Your repository already has `task/something` as a file, and the file system doesn't allow it to be a folder at the same time for `task/something/something_else`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks - that was it. Thanks all