# How To Pull Latest Files from Dev Branch and NOT master?

Tags: linux, git, github, terminal, virtualbox

I'm new to Git and I'm really confused here. I have a HTTPS from my github, and I am using terminal from a virtual box to try to pull the latest files from one of my branches.

Everytime I use the following command:

**git pull** ***http-link*** or **git clone *http-link***
it only pulls the files from the master branch, and not ALL the branches. I know this because when I run **git branch** I only see the master branch, and not the develop branch that I have in github. I want the files from this develop branch (NOT master) so I can push the changes to that branch, before merging to master. Please advise.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch

Comment: You basically need to fetch a remote branch, you need to create a remote tracking branch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git fetch remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it only pulls the files from the master branch, and not ALL the branches

The rules for `pull` are somewhat configuration-dependent, but I can tell you that when you `clone` it is getting the entire history (all branches) unless you give it specific options telling it not to (such as `--single-branch`).

> I know this because when I run git branch I only see the master branch

That's because by default `git branch` lists the *local* branches, and not every known branch from the remote(s).  You can say

```
git branch -a
```

to see the rest.  They'll appear with names like

```
remotes/origin/branch-name
```

because what you have are not proper branches; rather these are sort of "bookmarks" that tell you where the remotes branches were, when last you fetched from the remote.

By default, cloning does *not* automatically create local branches for every branch on the remote (but it *does* fetch the branches).  By default cloning *does* check out the default branch from the remote (`master` in this case), creating the local branch for it.  And there are shortcuts built in to git such that, in a typical configuration with a single remote, you can say

```
git checkout branch-name
```

to create the local branch corresponding to the remote's `branch-name` branch.

Note that when you do this initial checkout, you *don't* want to say

```
git checkout remotes/origin/branch-name
```

because that does something else.  Rather than create the local branch, this simply puts you in "detached `HEAD`" state, with `HEAD` on the same commit as the remote branch.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very insightful and helpful!