# Xcode gives error upon checkout: The branch could not be created because one named “master” already exists

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

In Xcocde's source navigator, I've selected a branch then right click and hit `checkout`. Yet I get the following error:

[image]

**The branch could not be created because one named “master” already exists.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting this error message because I've selected a branch under the **Remotes** group and was trying to checkout out to that branch.

I suppose when you `checkout` a *remote* branch that doesn't have a *local* branch with that name, then git will attempt to *create* that branch. For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464499/how-does-git-checkout-work-after-git-fetch). But since I already had that branch created it was failing.

There is nothing wrong with trying to create a local branch off a fetched branch, but that was just not what I wanted to do. I just wanted to checkout to an existing branch.

So all I had to do was:

Xcode >> Source control navigator >> **Branches** >> select branch and checkout.

I was previously doing:

Xcode >> Source control navigator >> **Remotes** >> select branch and checkout.

And for the above mentioned reason it was failing.