# Git-Intellij :Remote branch does not show up in local repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am using the below version of Pycharm from intellij family:

[image]

I have some branches in remote origin, but they do not show up in the local repository. Please find the below image.

I have done the `Fetch` from `VCS -> Git -> Fetch` but they are not still there. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a local branch to track the remote branch. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch#9537923) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch).

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on a remote branch which you want to be local and click "Checkout"