# git branching methods - what does -t mean in the context of git?

Tags: git

I had a problem with git

[Git fetch remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537392/git-fetch-remote-branch)

This answer solved it, I needed to do

`git checkout -t remotes/origin/branch-name`

What does `-t` mean...?

I can't find any answers on google or here...

Comment: Each Git sub-command has *its own* flags. For `git checkout`, `-t` is short for `--track`, as [lyzlisa answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72279984/1256452), but for `git ls-files` for instance, `-t` is just `-t`, a semi-deprecated feature, and for `git ls-tree` it makes `git ls-tree` show tree objects (useful only when combined with `-r`).

Answer (score 3):

You can get more information on a specific command using `--help` flag. In this case, `git checkout --help` would show you that `-t` is the shorthand form for `--track`.